# How to install your own library with Arduino IDE 1.8.5?

Tags: arduino-ide, library

I'm struggling a bit with Arduino language + its IDE not being 100% real C++. I wrote my own I2C library for a sensor but can't get the IDE's compiler to recognise it. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

I get `no such file or directory` for all of these things I've tried:

- Include the `.h` file by absolute and relative path in the `.ino` code
- Put `.cpp` +  `.h` files in ~/Arduino/libraries
- Put `.cpp` +  `.h` files in ~/sketchbook/libraries
- Put `.cpp` +  `.h` files in ~/sketchbook/libraries/mylibrary
- Put `.cpp` +  `.h` files in ~/sketchbook/libraries/mylibrary and try to "install" the library in the IDE (Sketch -> Include library -> Manage libraries; it's not listed)

I'm following the [official guide here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Libraries). Any ideas on how to get the compiler to recognise my library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create the folder ~/Arduino/libraries/MyLibrary
2. Place the library files in there named as:

   - ~/Arduino/libraries/MyLibrary/MyLibrary.h
   - ~/Arduino/libraries/MyLibrary/MyLibrary.cpp
3. **Restart the IDE if it is running**
4. Use `#include <MyLibrary.h>` in your sketch

This is assuming your sketchbook is set to ~/Arduino - change that to wherever the sketchbook is set to (check in Preferences for that location).

Note that in Linux capitalisation is *important*. The filesystem is case sensitive, and the name of your folder should have the same name and capitalisation as the name of your header file.

Comment: No, but what capitalisation you use on your files you should also use on the folder, and you must use in the #include.

Comment: I'm not sure how critical it is, but it *should* be the same as the .h file.

Comment: You're right, it was the sketchbook location. I had fiddled with my installation a few times, and hadn't updated the preferences. Thank you.

Comment: Have you confirmed where you sketchbook folder actually is? Mine is ~/Arduino (I updated the answer to reflect that).

Comment: I would add that the source files can be in `src` subfolder of the library folder to not mix them with library configuration files and github readme file if you want to publish the library. `~/Arduino/libraries/MyLibrary/src/MyLibrary.h` https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification

Comment: Only if you have a library.properties (or whatever it is) to describe the library...

Comment: *"I'm not sure how critical it is"* When multiple files match the `#include` directive, the IDE uses folder name matching as one of the factors for determining which gets preference. That's the only time a matching folder name matters.

Comment: @per1234 UECIDE is more strict and needs the folder named properly so it can identify precisely what a library is. It needs that so it can do proper recursive library inclusion, which is something the Arduino IDE sadly lacks.